# Insert a line with different values

Tags: mysql, sql, database

```
CREATE TABLE `playersrb` (
`position` numeric(24) DEFAULT NULL,
`piece_color` enum('B','R') NOT NULL,
`id` numeric(30) DEFAULT NULL,
`last_action` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp()
)
```

How to insert  a line ?
position  the number 12
piece_color the R
id  0  and 1 . I want to have two numbers here

I did

```
INSERT INTO `playersrb` VALUES('12','R','01');
```

The returned error was:

```
00:20:16    INSERT INTO `playersrb` VALUES('12','R','01')   Error Code: 1136. Column count doesn't match value count at row 1   0.00062 sec
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! When you post a question, make sure it is easily readable, and you post the errors you encountered, it makes it a lot easier to answer!

A few other notes on your query, you do not need to enclose the table name in quotation marks. You also should define one of the columns as a Primary Key (probably ID). Lastly, in your insert, you can replace '01' with just 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify the columns to insert if you would like to use VALUES. In your case, it would be something like this:

```
INSERT INTO `playersrb` (`position`, `piece_color`, `id`) VALUES ('12','R','01');
```

Answer (score 1):

Your table name is different than what you are trying to INSERT into.
You also are not inserting the same number of values as there are columns, so you either need to insert a value for each column, or define the columns you want to enter into.

This statement will work to insert a row.

```
INSERT INTO playersrb VALUES('12','R','01', now());
```

I am assuming you wanted `last_action` to default to now(), but to do that you will need to define the columns like this:

```
INSERT INTO 
    playersrb
    (position, piece_color, id)
VALUES
    ('12', 'R', '01');
```